# Conserved Noether current

Tags: conservation-laws, field-theory, dirac-equation, noethers-theorem

I want to prove that in the massless limit $m=0$, Noether's current is conserved:

$$ \partial_{\mu} J^{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} (\psi^{\dagger} \gamma_0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 \psi ) =0$$

I don't really know how to go about it. So far I tried this:

$$ \partial_{\mu} (\psi^{\dagger} \gamma_0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 \psi ) = \partial_{\mu} (\psi^{\dagger}) \gamma_0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 \psi  +  \psi^{\dagger} \gamma_0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 \partial_{\mu} (\psi ) $$

for the second term I used the anticommutation relation $\{ \gamma_5,\gamma^{\mu} \} = 0$ and multiplied and divided by $i$ to obtain Dirac's equation in the massless limit:

$$ \partial_{\mu} (\psi^{\dagger} \gamma_0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 \psi ) = \partial_{\mu} (\psi^{\dagger}) \gamma_0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 \psi  -  \psi^{\dagger} \gamma_0 \gamma_5 \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} (\psi ) $$

$$ \partial_{\mu} (\psi^{\dagger} \gamma_0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 \psi ) = \partial_{\mu} (\psi^{\dagger}) \gamma_0 \gamma^{\mu} \gamma_5 \psi  +i  \psi^{\dagger} \gamma_0 \gamma_5 
\underbrace{ i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} (\psi )}_{=0} $$

now I don't know how to handle the first term.

Comment: I think you could either use the use the conjugate Dirac's equation or you could use integration by parts to reobtain a similar expression to the second term and then reuse Dirac's equation to prove that it is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have
$$\partial_\mu (\psi^\dagger \gamma_0 \gamma^\mu \gamma_5 \psi) = \partial_\mu(\psi^\dagger) \gamma_0 \gamma^\mu\gamma_5 \psi,$$
we need to find an equation that says something about $\partial_\mu(\psi^\dagger)$.  All we have are the equations of motion (the massless Dirac equation $ 0 = \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi$), so we can try taking the adjoint of that:
$$ 0 = \partial_\mu(\psi^\dagger) (\gamma^\mu)^\dagger\\
= \partial_\mu(\psi^\dagger) \gamma^0 \gamma^0 (\gamma^\mu)^\dagger\\
= \partial_0(\psi^\dagger) \gamma^0 \gamma^0 \gamma^0 - \partial_i(\psi^\dagger) \gamma^0 \gamma^0 \gamma^i\\
= \partial_0(\psi^\dagger) \gamma^0 \gamma^0 + \partial_i(\psi^\dagger) \gamma^0 \gamma^i  \\
= \partial_\mu(\psi^\dagger) \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu. $$

There's probably a slicker way to do this, but this works.  The fact that $\gamma^0$ is Hermitian and $\gamma^i$ are anti-Hermitian cancels out the fact that $\{\gamma^0,\gamma^0\} = 2 I $ and  $\{\gamma^0,\gamma^i\} = 0$ so it stays Lorentz-covariant all along.